# Update R 4.0.5 to R 4.1.1 with conda on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, conda

I tried (using conda 4.9.2) :

> conda install -c conda-forge r-base

Based on the conda website [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-base)

It should install R 4.1.1 but it's installing 4.0.5.
Why ?

Comment: Probably due to existing pakcages. have you tried to specify the version `conda install -c conda-forge r-base=4.1.1` or create a new env with only `r-base` in it?

Comment: Yeah I was already in a new environement.

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge r-base=4.1.1 did the trick ,thanks !